# Javascript can't call an object inside a function

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I am new to javascript. I am trying to call an object from inside a function to allow me to get a variable from a flash file at set intervals. For some reason the object is not working inside the timer function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>DIY Map</title>

<style>
 * { margin:0; padding:0; }
</style>

</head>
<body style="font-family:verdana;color:#999; background-image:url('bg.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JavaScriptFlashGateway.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Exception.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/FlashTag.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/FlashSerializer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/FlashProxy.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
 var uid = new Date().getTime();
 var flashProxy = new FlashProxy(uid, 'js/JavaScriptFlashGateway.swf');
    var tag = new FlashTag('world.swf?data_file=data.xml, 600, 325);
    tag.setFlashvars('lcId='+uid);
    tag.write(document);


</script>

//flashProxy.call works here:
<p><a href="javascript:flashProxy.call('zoomOut');">Zoom Out</a>

<a href="javascript:flashProxy.call('refreshData','other_data.xml');">Get new data</a>

<p><a href="javascript:flashProxy.call('getZoom');">getZoom</a> | <a href="javascript:flashProxy.call('getCoords');">getCoords</a></p>



<script type="text/javascript">
// Start the refreshing process

var seconds = 3;
var zoom;
var coords;

//timer loop
function checkmap()
{
//flashProxy doesn't work here
flashProxy.call('getCoords');     
flashProxy.call('getZoom');   
alert (coords);
alert (zoom);    


setTimeout('checkmap()',seconds * 1000);
}
checkmap();



//Returns results here:
function gotCoords(n)
{
    coords = n;
}
function gotZoom(n)
{
    zoom = n;   
}
</script>
```

To clarify, I am trying to get the `flashProxy.call('****')` to work in the `checkmap()` function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You were supposed to ask a question

Comment: I am trying to get the flashProxy.call('****') to work in the checkmap() function

Comment: What a lot of code there is there (and what is a lot is in referenced files we can't see)… and "Doesn't work" is not a helpful description of a problem. How does the thing that happens differ from the thing you expect to happen and what error messages are displayed (don't forget to check the JS console)?

Comment: Ok... sorry. There are no errors in the console. I am trying to get the current zoom level and coordinates from a flash map every x seconds. The strangest part is that in IE... every 3 seconds it alert's 'undefined'... yet in firefox the first 3 alert's are 'undefined'... the ones after that work flawlessly.

Comment: The flash proxy stuff I believe is standard code written by 'Macromedia' (must be old) for communication between Javascript and Flash. Using flashProxy.call it makes a request and then it returns to gotCoords or gotZoom...

Comment: I excpected the first result to be 'undefined' as the alert is called after the request and not the response... but that was just for testing... still working after the third request seems peculiar.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem... it was that because there was no timer to start the inital flashproxy.call it was executing before the flash was loaded. I just replaced

```
checkmap();
```

with another

```
setTimeout('checkmap()',seconds * 1000);
```

Thanks everyone anyway

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you have an extra/unclosed script tag in your source?  This would cause problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // This is your opening tag




<script type="text/javascript"> // Oops, this is parsed by the script engine
 var uid = new Date().getTime(); 
 var flashProxy = new FlashProxy(uid, 'js/JavaScriptFlashGateway.swf'); 
    var tag = new FlashTag('world.swf?data_file=data.xml, 600, 325); 
    tag.setFlashvars('lcId='+uid); 
    tag.write(document); 


</script>
```

The above code would throw a syntax error in any javascript engine and halt further execution.

Your source is also missing a `'` on the following line:

```
var tag = new FlashTag('world.swf?data_file=data.xml, 600, 325);
```

Comment: opps, my mistake... that was caused by me tidying my code up for presentation on here :P Thanks anyway :)